# java.lang.NullPointerException: (Fragment)

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I'm trying to create a Navigation Menu + Tabs, the code for this is fine.

Now I've implemented some code I had as an Activity in a `Fragment` in order to add it to the `Tabs` viewer.

When I run the `code` the app works just **fine**..
Until I swipe right to the other Tab and then the App crashed and I get this from the `logcat`:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to write to field 'android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl android.support.v4.app.Fragment.mFragmentManager' on a null object reference
```

I'm leaving you my Main Activity, 'cause I think there's the issue, if you think you might need some Fragments like the Tabs, please just ask!

CODE: http://pastebin.com/TTcJMR77

Comment: Please include the *relevant* code in the question.

Comment: Did you see the Pastebin? @Matsemann

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add default case on your switch in `getItem(int position)` method:

```
default:
return new Fragment();
```

Instead of

```
return null;
```

Like this:

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return new YourFragment();
        default:
            return new Fragment();
    }
}
```

Comment: Just to know, are you from Italy?

Comment: I think I need to change all my imports on the support.v4 on the simple .app one right?

Comment: Yes, if you want, we can move discussion to chat.

Comment: Might be a better option for everyone yeah

Comment: But I think ya can start it, not me

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93212/discussion-between-michele-lacorte-and-insside-you).